# parameter?: type | undefined vs parameter?: type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand the difference between two ways of declaring an optional parameter for a function:

```
parameter?: type
```

and

```
parameter?: type | undefined
```

From what I understand, the first is a shorthand for

```
parameter: type | undefined = undefined
```

Is the second way any different from this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An optional parameter resolves its parameter to undefined if nothing has been passed.

Therefore, the second statement is redundant as it is an optional parameter but also allows 'type' and undefined.

No difference in what it does as long as type is strictly typed.